# Mipmapping in OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl, mipmaps

I'm having a lot of trouble getting mipmaps to work. I'm using OpenGL 1.1, and I don't have glu, so I'm using the following texture initiation code:

```
  glGenTextures(1,&texname);
  glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,texname);
  glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S,GL_REPEAT);
  glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T,GL_REPEAT);
  glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,GL_NEAREST);
  glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,GL_NEAREST_MIPMAP_NEAREST);
  w=width;h=height;
  for(int i=0;i<mipmaps;i++,w/=2,h/=2)
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D,i,GL_RGBA8,w,h,0,GL_RGBA,GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,tex[i]);
```

Variables:

```
// data types:
unsigned long int *tex[20];
int mipmaps, width, height, w, h;
GLuint texname;
```

`tex` is an array that holds the list of the texture mipmap pixel arrays. The mipmaps are processed correctly (I tested them individually). `mipmaps` is the number of mipmaps that reduce down the original image to a 1x1 pixel texture (the original texture is 256x256 - so at this point in the code it's 8). `width` and `height` are the dimensions of the original texture (256x256).

The result is that it doesn't even use a texture. Everything just appears flat grays (gray due to the lighting).

Is there something I'm forgetting? I've checked [this reference](http://www.glprogramming.com/red/chapter09.html), and I can't find any conflicts.

Other details: In total, I'm enabling GL_DEPTH_TEST, GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_LIGHTING, GL_CULL_FACE, GL_FOG (and GL_LIGHT0, GL_LIGHT1 which probably don't make a difference).
Also, I am using Mesa 3D's implementation of OpenGL (Mesa version 4.0 which translates to OpenGL version 1.3) if that might have anything to do with it.

**EDIT:**

The issue is, the texture works fine (not using mipmaps) the moment I change GL_NEAREST_MIPMAP_NEAREST to GL_NEAREST. So, I can't see how it could be any other code - at least I can't think of anything else it might be.

Comment: Is glGenerateMipmap available in 1.1?

Comment: no - I researched that, and I think it was added in 3.0

Comment: Are there any problems when you don't try to generate mipmaps?

Comment: Heh, nope! That's why it's so weird. In fact, to make it work, I simply change the GL_NEAREST_MIPMAP_NEAREST to GL_NEAREST, and suddenly it works, but doesn't use the mipmaps.

Comment: What is the value of mipmaps and the data type of tex?

Comment: unsigned long int *tex[20];
and mipmaps = 8;

Comment: at this point in the file there's no difference in data (when viewed as void* data) between bytes and unsigned long ints. Plus, it does work when I'm not dealing with mipmaps. (p.s. should we move this to a chat?)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28136/discussion-between-uberwulu-and-auto)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The value of mipmaps is 8.  Your image is 256x256.  Therefore, you should have 9 levels of mipmapping (256,128,64,32,16,8,4,2,1).  If one is missing, you'll lose your texture.